# Identical content search between files of different names?

Tags: search, awk, text, diff

I do not know if it is possible to compare the contents of text files among other files in a second folder. I need the program to only search for matching strings and if it finds them, show both lines of the files with the matching string.

I have tried with diff but I do not get the result I expect.

An example of what I'm looking for is:

Assuming I have two folders and within each one are the text files I want to compare.

**Folder1**/*test.txt:*

```
example1 - A
exampleA - A
example2 - B
exampleB - C
example3 - C
exampleC - D
```

**Folder2**/*test_different_name.txt:*

```
exampleA - A
example3 - B
exampleB - C
exampleC - D
example1 - E
```

**The result** should be the matching strings of the compared files:

I added this bit as the formatting would not fit in a comment.  If this is **not** the desired result, please delete it from the question! CharlesGreen

```
|==========================|
|String    |File 1 |File 2 |
|--------------------------|
|example1  |A      |E      |
|example3  |C      |B      |
|==========================|
```

> Note that only the matching texts are printed and when the entire line does not match, the differences are printed on the screen.

Comment: Does [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is a good solution for you? It has file and directory comparison.

Comment: @N0rbert I just tried it and it seems that it's not what I'm looking for. When the files have different names it does not show the content differences and is not able to track if there are other files with the same content. Also, for what I need, there will be a large amount of mismatched text and it would be a task that would take a lot of time.

Comment: So, you are looking to find the lines in the files with the same first word, but different endings, and then show the lines from both files?

Comment: @αғsнιη Try again :), it's true, my objective was not clear. What I hope is that instead of looking for strings of text from a text list, we search for strings of matching texts between the files in folders 1 and 2 and if there is identical text, the result will be printed indicating the file that contains the text.

Comment: @CharlesGreen You almost have it! :) What I'm looking for is that if the entire text string does not exactly match, the lines of both files should be show. If they match, nothing should be show on the screen.

Comment: I added an edit to your question, if I have it wrong, please delete the edit.

Comment: Thank you! @CharlesGreen I have included and updated the examples. I hope it gets better understood :)

Comment: I think this could be done with awk, but I'm not smart enough to figure this out.  I know there are some bright minds on this site...

Answer (score 2):

Here you can do with `awk` as:

```
awk -F'-' 'NR == FNR { hold[$1]= $2; next } $2 != hold[$1] { print $1, hold[$1], $2 }' file1 file2
example3   C  B
example1   A  E
```

we are reading file1 into an `awk` associated array called `hold` with the key as first column and value from second column, where columns delimited by a hyphen we specified with `awk`'s `-F'-'` option until the `N`umber of `R`ecords is equal with `F`ile `N`umber of `R`ecords - which it always true for first input file only, here file1.

then check column2 of file2 against the key with same first column we have saved in array, if those were different in second column, then we will print that.